# Possible reasons of linux open call returning EINVAL

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to make a system call in my source code as follows.

```
int file;
file = open(argv[index], O_RDONLY);
```

Where the command line arguement is a path to a binary file in my filesystem. But this call throws me an `EINVAL` error. I have checked the existence of file and the required permissions to access it.

Any suggestions on what circumstances the `EINVAL` error will be thrown out.

Comment: Is this exactly how are you calling it? Have you tried different files? Are there any warnings (with `-Wall`)?

Comment: Thanks Banthar.. Yes I tried opening different files. The error is seen for only certain binary files. I should double check on the warnings.

Comment: Is the file just a normal binary file, and not a socket or device? What kind of filesystem is it on? Is it actually only O_RDONLY in the flags?

Comment: Yes, it is a normal binary file. It is on a Extended filesystem. It has only O_RDONLY flags.

Comment: I'm wondering if you did something funky when entering the name?

Comment: ext2? ext3? ext4?  Kernel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause of failure:**

There were two processes say (process-1 and process-2) that were executing in close sequel and was trying to open this binary file. Since my system (embedded device) will crash after this open call, the debugs splitted out weren't proper and it made me to suspect the process-1. But the actual culprit is process-2 who was opening the binary with `O_RDWR` flag. But my file system (network mount) was mounted as "**read only file system**".

**Points to be taken care:**

Refining the **perror** prints it should be the right cause of the problem as "**Read Only File System**". So my initial **perror** description must be a uncleared value of any of the previous erroneous call. One learning here is to use **perror** with care, so as avoid analysing misleading error message.

**Possible circumstances the `EINVAL` error will be thrown out**:

The open call will show an `EINVAL` if we use O_SYNC (or) related flags for the file which we are not supposed to use. I conclude this based on the documentation  as previously mentioned by Rafe.

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation suggests that this is because your implementation of `open()` does not support synchronized IO for the file you are trying to open.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Specifically, the underlying kernel driver which the user open() call uses does not implement fsync().

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that `argv[index]` actually contains the filename and that `O_RDONLY` hasn't been overridden somehow (`O_RDONLY` should equal 0), check your system log via the `dmesg` command and make sure that nothing funky has happened in-kernel.