# RH Linux Mutex lock debugging

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, mutex

I will be thankful if somebody experienced with C++, multithreaded code can shed some light on a mutex problem. It is running on Red hat Linux 5.4. We are debugging legacy code that I did not write. It is suppose to do very high calls per second, and response time is 3-5 miliseconds. We are running about 400 threads in the main application.

One thing I don't like about this app is the use of smart pointers everywhere (there is mutex call any time SPtr goes out of scope). The person who wrote this seems addicted to SPtrs. Lots of funcations take SPtr as an argument.

The application can run fine for few hours and then we suddenly get mutex EINVAL at the time of lock (return code 22). I have seen core dumps and it shows different stack trace, no single place that causes it.

What tools would you recommend to debug this? Can this happen due to memory or stack corruption (meaning something unrelated to mutexes)? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try valgrind, with the helgrind tool as well as the default one.

Comment: 400 threads doing work? Or blocked on read system calls?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055060/possible-reasons-of-linux-open-call-returning-einval did you have a look at this ?

Comment: Sam, the input coming to app is 1 call per milisecond (1000 cps). The calls are sent to another application (tcp) that talks to database. Then the response comes back and is sent back to the caller. This is VoIP application. So to answer your question, the threads are busy processing either incoming information or outgoing information (not blocked).

Comment: Flexo, valgrind with helgrind looks promising. I will try it out. Right now they have no means of even doing decent shutdown of application where all threads do graceful exit. They just kill the application if restart is needed. I am in process of puting in code to do proper shutdown (valgrind needs it).

Answer (score 2):

`EINVAL` on a `pthread_mutex_lock` call means that the lock has not been properly initialized.  It can also mean that the lock has been destroyed by `pthread_mutex_destroy`.  Either of thes can occur if you have memory or stack corruption -- if you've overwritten the mutex object with random garbage, or you're trying to use an object with a mutex after its destructor has been called.

If you print a mutex object in gdb, you'll see something like:

```
$5 = {
  __data = {
    __lock = 0, 
    __count = 0, 
    __owner = 0, 
    __nusers = 0, 
    __kind = -1, 
    __spins = 0, 
    __list = {
      __prev = 0x0, 
      __next = 0x0
    }
  }, 
  __size = '\000' <repeats 16 times>"\377, \377\377\377", '\000' <repeats 19 times>, 
  __align = 0
}
```

in this case, a `kind` field of -1 mean that the mutex has been destroyed.  Kind fields of 0, 1, or 2 mean valid mutexes.  The other fields should all contain small integers or valid looking pointers.  If you see random looking garbage, it means that the mutex was probably clobbered by something.

Comment: Chris, thanks. I will use valgrind to make sure any memory related problems show up and get resolved. Probably gdb can be setup to stop if the mutex object __kind field has value other than -1, 0, 1, 2. That is interesting information I did not know.