# When does the open() function fail with an Invalid argument?

Tags: c

I am using fswebcam to capture images from a USB device.
The command is `fswebcam -d /dev/v4l/by-id/device-id-of-usb-webcam-index0 /home/myhome/output.jpg`.
Usually, it works fine.
But once it gave the following error:

```
Failed to open /dev/v4l/by-id/device-id-of-usb-webcam-index0: Invalid argument
[1m--- Opening /dev/v4l/by-id/device-id-of-usb-webcam-index0...
[0m[0mTrying source module v4l2...
[0m[31mError opening device: /dev/v4l/by-id/device-id-of-usb-webcam-index0
[0m[31mopen: Invalid argument
[0m[0mTrying source module v4l1...
[0m[31mError opening device: /dev/v4l/by-id/device-id-of-usb-webcam-index0
[0m[31mopen: Invalid argument
[0m[31mUnable to find a source module that can read /dev/v4l/by-id/device-id-of-usb-webcam-index0.
```

I tried to see when this happens by reading fswebcam's source code at https://github.com/fsphil/fswebcam/blob/master/src_v4l2.c#L817

Basically the code `s->fd = open(src->source, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);` fails with `errno` being set to `EINVAL`.

But I am wondering when would this happen.

I tried making a symlink to an non-existing file, but it didn't work (prints `open: No such file or directory`)

Is there a way to make the `open` function return with errno `EINVAL`?

Comment: See this entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055060/possible-reasons-of-linux-open-call-returning-einval

Comment: [The official POSIX `open` reference page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) say that `EINVAL` is returned either if "he implementation does not support synchronized I/O for this file" or "The value of the oflag argument is not valid". Specific implementations might add to that list. See e.g. [the Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

Comment: the statement `s->fd = open(src->source, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);` doesn't seem to be using synchronized I/O. also like i mentioned the fswebcam command always works, and has only failed like 1 time in 1000 runs.